# Problem with USBSetup not declared

Tags: arduino-uno, hid

Recently I've got into the Arduino USB HID stuff, so I've been trying it out. i found the library [fingerprintusbhost](https://github.com/keyboardio/FingerprintUSBHost) which should in theory get the OS its plugged in.

However, I've come across this error and I'm not sure how to fix or make it work. I've been looking in the library itself, but with my limited knowledge I don't know what is wrong or how to fix it.

```
In file included from /home/tdvds/Documents/arduino uno/Material_Rubber_Ducky_Arduino_UNO_R3/sketch_mar20a/sketch_mar20a.ino:2:0:
/home/tdvds/Arduino/libraries/FingerprintUSBHost/src/FingerprintUSBHost.h:38:55: error: expected class-name before '{' token
 class FingerprintUSBHost_ : public PluggableUSBModule {
                                                       ^
/home/tdvds/Arduino/libraries/FingerprintUSBHost/src/FingerprintUSBHost.h:52:23: error: 'USBSetup' has not been declared
     int getDescriptor(USBSetup& setup);
                       ^~~~~~~~
/home/tdvds/Arduino/libraries/FingerprintUSBHost/src/FingerprintUSBHost.h:53:16: error: 'USBSetup' has not been declared
     bool setup(USBSetup& setup);
                ^~~~~~~~

exit status 1

Compilation error: exit status 1
```

Before you say "it's not a Leonardo", you can actually do it with an Uno as well, although it's a bit odder than a Leonardo.

Comment: To do this on an UNO involves reprogramming the 32U4 serial bridge chip.  You can't use the same set of libraries that you do with a Leonardo.

Comment: So how exactly are you doing it "a bit odder"? Are you compiling for the Atmega32U4 and flashing it with your code?

Answer (score 0):

This is as expected, if you try to use `PluggableUSBModule` on an Uno (or any board that doesn't have `USBCON` defined).

To avoid such errors, and get a meaningful compilation error message, you should include a compiler check such as

```cpp
#if !defined(USBCON)
#error PluggableUSBModule can only be used with an USB MCU.
#endif
```

just after the `#include`s at the top of the library's header file, like so

```cpp
#include <stdint.h>
#include <Arduino.h>
#include "PluggableUSB.h"

#if !defined(USBCON)
#error PluggableUSBModule can only be used with an USB MCU.
#endif
```

In short, if the [FingerprintUSBHost.h](https://github.com/keyboardio/FingerprintUSBHost/blob/master/src/FingerprintUSBHost.h) had such a check, then users of the library wouldn't be so confused. You should probably raise a Github issue for the author of the `FingerprintUSBHost` library, pointing out this issue.

---

##### Reproducing the error

FWIW, it is easy to reproduce this error, by using the code from this example, [Issue with writing USB Mass Storage "PluggableUSB.h" Module](https://forum.arduino.cc/t/issue-with-writing-usb-mass-storage-pluggableusb-h-module/578660). Enter the code for the three files (the main sketch, `MassStorage.cpp` and `MassStorage.h`) and compile, with the Uno board selected. You will get the error

```
MassStorage can only be used with an USB MCU.
```

Then remove the three lines of the compiler check from `MassStorage.h`:

```cpp
#if !defined(USBCON)
#error MassStorage can only be used with an USB MCU.
#endif
```

and then try to compile. You will get the same errors as you have in your post.

However, if you compile the unaltered original code, with a Leonardo board selected (which *does* have `USBCON` defined), you will not see any errors.